# Why wpf window respects my screen height when printing? It gets trimmed after I print the window to my printer

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, uwp

My screen height is 768 and the window height is 1200 then  when I was going to print the window to my printer, it gets truncated because my screen height is only 768. I used print dialog to achieve the printing and the problem is that the window height is supposedly 1200 but it respects my screen.

This is the window that I wanted to print but is truncated.
[image]
[image: this is the continuation of the image but truncated]

Comment: There are more controls and text below but I only crop a portion, to show that it is truncated.

Comment: You need to show us some code. You're anyway not supposed to print a window, but the document instead. A printer is a different output device than a display and needs to be handled differently.

Answer (score 1):

When printing it will only print the viewable area of the screen if you don't put the view into a document style. I ran into this problem before and when you are doing the job portion you have to convert it to a document first then push it through the job. Once that is done you can print the document instead of the view bounds (screen)

Comment: I already fixed it,  I just to printed the  root layout of the window (Grid) not the window itself  and that's it.

Comment: One of the other issues I had to slowly work through was how much ink was used. It seems by default it uses heavy ink so you can adjust the darkness of the ink as well